# DataGridView Image Button Cell - vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, imagebutton

Does anyone know how to programme up a “Delete Image Button” using an Icon for a DataGridView in Visual Studio .Net

I am struggling find trying to get my last column to have a delete icon instead of the word "Delete" and I want to display a little dustbin icon.

I have tried looking in that many places and I am unable to get this to work.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 

    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs)
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\icon_delete.jpg")
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.CellBounds.Left + 10, e.CellBounds.Top + 5, 10, 10)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Would appreciate some help if anyone knows. Thanks in Advance. Kuldip.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to look at the following answer. I managed to get a full solution working.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/215e3c61-6a1e-4f7d-8c53-534680fe2c87/display-image-button-in-a-datagridview-vbnet?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
Private Sub YourDataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvBilancioAttivita.CellFormatting

    If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Or e.RowIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    If YourDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "YourDeleteColumn" Then
        e.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\icon_delete.jpg")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Great Thanks you very much appreciate that. I will have a go.